# Server send message to client

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a Android application that uses TCP/IP. I can easily send a message to the server to the client but I can figure out how to send a message from the server to the client. I've looked around and can't find a answer. Is it just some kind of output writer?

```
Public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    Handler updateConversationHandler;
    Thread serverThread = null;
    private TextView text;
    public static final int SERVERPORT = 6000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
        updateConversationHandler = new Handler();
        this.serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
        this.serverThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class ServerThread implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            Socket socket = null;
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                    new Thread(commThread).start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {
        private Socket clientSocket;
        private BufferedReader input;
        public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        try {
            this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                String read = input.readLine();
                updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class updateUIThread implements Runnable {
    private String msg;
    public updateUIThread(String str) {
        this.msg = str;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        text.setText("");
        if (msg != null){
            text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"binary message sent: "+ msg + "\n");
            String[] list_bin = new String[list_command.length];

            for(int i=0 ; i<list_command.length; i++){
                list_bin[i] = Integer.toBinaryString(i);                   
                if ( list_bin[i] == null ? msg == null : list_bin[i].equals(msg)){
                    msg = list_command[i];
                }
            }

            text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"Found input : "+ msg + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

How do I have the server send a message to the client?

Comment: It's exactly the same in both directions. Hard to see what your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `OutputStreamWriter` on `clientSocket.getOutputStream`, and write to it from a separate thread.

Comment: Thanks but I have no idea how to do that

Comment: You need to do pretty much exactly the same thing you have done fore reading, replacing `InputStream` with `OutputStream`. If you are still confused check the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)